# Guide, tutorial for Joomla and a bit more information

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, zen-cart

May I ask is there any tutorial, guide website or videos that can guide me with template/theme building from scratch for Virtuemart 2.0.8?

Also do you suggest using Joomla with Virtuemart or Zen Cart for making an e-commerce website and I mean making a template and theme from scratch using HTML, CSS and Jquery.

Also I'm planning to add a text file into my database automatically from a ftp server every 8 hours so as to update the product prices of the site automatically. I know with Virtuemart I can do this with CSVI but is there any similar for Zen Cart?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not experienced with HTML, CSS and JQuery, then making your own template will be very hard. You would be better off using a free one or adapting it to suit your own needs.

As for your query about using Zen Cart or VirtueMart. I would recommend using VirtueMart as its fully integrated and however JVitals have made a bridge for those who would prefer to use Zen Cart which can be found [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/6701)